# ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO information (name, info) VALUES (:name, :info). SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, mysql

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO information (name, info)
>   VALUES (:name, :info). SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Getting this error and I have no idea what to do with it. Really beginner in these things and would need really simplified and explained answer for this. All the answers i have found for this problem have been way too complicated.

```
<?php

try{
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=3adad;dbname=efvcavc", "admin", "");
  // Set the PDO error mode to exception
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Attempt insert query execution
try{
  // create prepared statement
  $sql = "INSERT INTO information (name, info) VALUES (:name, :info)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  // bind parameters to statement
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_REQUEST['name']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':info', $_REQUEST['info']);


  // execute the prepared statement
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} catch(PDOException $e){
  die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">Nimesi:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="Name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Ajankohtaista päivitys</label>
        <input type="text" name="info" id="info">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check if form is __submitted__.

Comment: that relly didn´t answer my question. Most of the answers were way too complicated for beginner like me.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO information (name, info) VALUES (?, ?)";  $sql ->bind_param("ss", $name, $info);
  for more help https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp